# MVC: Visual Studio incorrectly launches application from a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

When I make some changes to a View and then click on the run icon, the application falls over; System.Web.HttpException: Path '(view name)' was not found.
Why is this happening and how do get VS to launch correctly?
When I write my own apps this does not happen, but I can't remember what I did to stop this happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your view file must have been selected(i.e clicked by mouse) when you run,select solution by clicking mouse before running it or else remove unwanted params from URL after running it.